Cats, winter and a café
Trying to recall this movie I saw perhaps 5 years ago. It might have been Canadian as I seem to recall there was a mix of French and English.
One of the persons / (main character) in the movie, girl, lived in a, (I believe), three or four story building. Believe she lived on second or third floor.
There are one (or some) murders in the neighborhood. The main character works at a cafe/diner where one of the investigators/detectives visit. The main character has a colleague in the diner that she talks with. It is winter. I seem to recall there is a or some cats that a neighbor of the main character has. Her neighbor is killed - do not recall by whom.
Believe the main character either killed or tries to hide the body. In some trash cans? The cats becomes a problem? I do not recall. It is rather fuzzy.
Know this is very vague, and the reason for this question is more about the scenery then the story-line. I'm also curious about some close-ups of an article in the local newspaper, (about the murder(s)), that I believe the detective reads at the diner/pub/bar/café.

Some more details:
The café:
IIRC the cafe has somewhat open space. Tables alongside a window and though the windows give good light the interior is dark brown (wood) and the weather is somewhat grayish winter giving it a low lighting.
IRC the building where the main character lives is plain 60s/70s? light yellow/white with balconies.
IIRC the main character befriends a male character that are suspected either by police or the viewer as being the culprit. Or perhaps she tried to put the blame on him, or err, I do not recall.

A lot of it sounds like the Canadian thriller Good Neighbours from 2010 that takes place in winter.

In an old apartment building, the new tenant of the fourth floor Victor has just arrived from China with his cat Balthazar and befriends the waitress of a Chinese restaurant Louise that lives on the second floor with her two beloved cats Mozart and Tia Maria and the handicap Spencer that is in a wheelchair and lives on the first floor. Louise is on edge with the news about the murders in her neighborhood and Victor, who is an elementary school teacher, brings her home everyday after the working period and falls in love with her. Meanwhile, their alcoholic neighbor Valérie Langlois hates Louise's cats and on the Christmas night, she poisons the pets. Louise decides to revenge against Valerie simulating an attack of the serial-killer. But when she is returning home, she meets the real killer and Victor also sees him.

Here's the trailer:




Bulls eye! Not sure how you found that from my description, but tanks a lot.
